# phpmailer create eml-message send via users outlook

Tags: php, email, outlook

The webserver (wampp) creates with phpmailer an eml-file

```
<?php
$mail->From = $usermail;
$mail->FromName = $username;
$mail->AddCustomHeader("X-Unsent: 1");
...
$mail->preSend();
$mail->getSentMIMEMessage());
$message=$mail->GetSentMIMEMessage();

$handle=fopen('message.eml','w');
fwrite($handle, $message);
fclose($handle);
?>
```

and this the message is send to user browser to be downloaded. The message is by default opened with outlook so that user is able to edit the message before sending it.

Now the problem is that user gets error message [0x80070005-0x0004dc-0x000524] telling that user is not allowed to send message on behalf of specified user.

The Exchange server is version 2013 and User Outlook 2010/2013.

Could you please help me to get rid of this security issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the EML file does not have `From` or `Sender` MIME headers.

Comment: Hello Dmitry. Thank you for your help. There was a standard `FROM` defined in phpmailer  'root@localhost', which i set now to blank and it works fine. In my code i had to set the `$mail->From = '';`